# Correlation between dichotomous variable and continuous variable

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation

I have two dataframes one (Lots) which is structured as follows:

| Lot Group | Lot Number | Booking Stage | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 216000.00 | HPRESM | 2020-08-28 |
| 2 | 890000.01 | PART | 2013-04-17 |

and the other one measurements as follows:

| Mid | Date | Measurement 1 | Measurement 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1901827 | 2020-08-28 | 44.5 | 23.22 |
| 2981632 | 2013-04-17 | 49.0 | 34.5 |

The date column in both dataframes has unique dates and they are identical in both dataframes, as they have the same length.

What I am trying to do is compute correlations between the measurement columns which is are continuous variables and the lot group which is either 1 (good lot) or 2 (bad lot i.e. a dichotomous variable. The measurement variables have a lot of NaNs over 50%. My question is that I tried to compute the Point-Biserial correlation as I read it is used to calculate correlation between these two type of variables but I get nan for the statistic and 1 for the p-value.

```py
columns = measurement.select_dtypes(exclude = ["object", "datetime"]).columns
for col in columns:
    stat, p  = ss.pointbiserialr(lots["LosGruppe"], measurement[col])
    print(f"Variable: {col}, Correlation: {stat}, P-Value: {p}")

Output:
Variable: Mes 1, Correlation: nan, P-Value: 1.0
Variable: Mes 2, Correlation: nan, P-Value: 1.0
Variable: Mes 3, Correlation: nan, P-Value: 1.0
Variable: Mes 4, Correlation: nan, P-Value: 1.0
Variable: Mes 5, Correlation: nan, P-Value: 1.0
```

What would you advise as a solution or cause of this issue and what is a suitable correlation method between such variables?

Comment: `measurement.dropna()[col]` might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point biserial correlation is a good approach here, but the problem you have is with the missing values. You will need to remove these first with `dropna()`